# How to Couple Advection Diffusion Reaction PDEs with FiPy

Tags: python, pde, fipy

I tried to solve 1D coupled PDEs for an advection-diffusion-reaction problem with the Matlab function Pdepe (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html). This function is not working properly in my case of a high advection term as compared to the diffusion term.
Therefore, I searched and found this option of using the Python library FiPy to solve my PDEs system.
My initial conditions are u1=1 for 4*L/10

My coupled equations are of the following form:

du1/dt = d/dx(D1 * du1/dx) + g * x * du1/dx - mu1 * u1 / (K + u1) * u2

du2/dt = d/dx(D2 * du2/dx) + g * x * du2/dx + mu2 * u1 / (K + u1) * u2

I tried to write it by combining the FiPy examples (examples.convection.exponential1DSource.mesh1D, examples.levelSet.advection.mesh1D, examples.cahnHilliard.mesh2DCoupled).

The following lines are not a working example but my first attempt to write the code. This is my first use of FiPy (out of the tests and examples of the documentation), so this might seem to miss the point completely for the regular users.

```
from fipy import *

g = 0.66
L = 10.
nx = 1000
mu1 = 1.
mu2 = 1.
K = 1.
D1 = 1.
D2 = 1.

mesh = Grid1D(dx=L / 1000, nx=nx)

x = mesh.cellCenters[0]
convCoeff = g*(x-L/2)

u10 = 4*L/10 < x < 6*L/10
u20 = 1.

u1 = CellVariable(name="u1", mesh=mesh, value=u10)
u2 = CellVariable(name="u2", mesh=mesh, value=u20)

## Neumann boundary conditions
u1.faceGrad.constrain(0., where=mesh.facesLeft)
u1.faceGrad.constrain(0., where=mesh.facesRight)
u2.faceGrad.constrain(0., where=mesh.facesLeft)
u2.faceGrad.constrain(0., where=mesh.facesRight)

sourceCoeff1 = -1*mu1*u1/(K+u1)*u2
sourceCoeff2 = 1*mu2*u1/(K+u1)*u2

eq11 = (TransientTerm(var=u1) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D1, var=u1) + ConvectionTerm(coeff=convCoeff))
eq21 = (TransientTerm(var=u2) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D2, var=u2) + ConvectionTerm(coeff=convCoeff))

eq12 = ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=sourceCoeff1, var=u1)
eq22 = ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=sourceCoeff2, var=u2)

eq1 = eq11 & eq12
eq2 = eq21 & eq22

eqn = eq1 & eq2
vi = Viewer((u1, u2))

for t in range(100):
    u1.updateOld()
    u2.updateOld()
    eqn.solve(dt=1.e-3)
    vi.plot()
```

Thank you for any suggestion or correction.
If you happen to know a good tutorial for this specific kind of problem, I would be happy to read it, since I did not find anything better than the examples in the FiPy documentation.

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are asking for suggestions/corrections on? If it's just an overall code review I would suggest posting in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you, never heard of it. It might be better to post it their indeed.

Comment: There are four equations but only two variables. The number of variables must equal the number of equations to have a closed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues:

- python [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) do not work in numpy and therefore do not work in FiPy. So, write

  ```py
  u10 = (4*L/10 < x) & (x < 6*L/10)
  ```

  Further, this makes `u10` a field of Booleans, which confuses FiPy, so 
  write

  ```py
  u10 = ((4*L/10 < x) & (x < 6*L/10)) * 1.
  ```

  or, better yet, write

  ```py
  u1 = CellVariable(name="u1", mesh=mesh, value=0., hasOld=True)
  u2 = CellVariable(name="u2", mesh=mesh, value=1., hasOld=True)
  u1.setValue(1., where=(4*L/10 < x) & (x < 6*L/10))
  ```
- `ConvectionTerm` takes a vector coefficient. One way to get this is

  ```py
  convCoeff = g*(x-L/2) * [[1.]]
  ```

  which represents a 1D rank-1 variable
- If you declare which `Variable` a `Term` applies to, you must do it for all `Term`s, so write, e.g.,

  ```py
  ConvectionTerm(coeff=convCoeff, var=u1)
  ```
- `ConvectionTerm(coeff=g*x, var=u1)`
  does not represent g * x * du1/dx. It represents d(g * x * u1)/dx. So, I believe you'll want

  ```py
  ConvectionTerm(coeff=convCoeff, var=u1) - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=g, var=u1)
  ```
- `ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=sourceCoeff1, var=u1` does not represent 
  `-1*mu1*u1/(K+u1)*u2`, rather it represents `-1*mu1*u1/(K+u1)*u2*u1`. So, for best coupling between equations, write

  ```py
  sourceCoeff1 = -mu1*u1/(K+u1)
  sourceCoeff2 = mu2*u2/(K+u1)

  ... ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=sourceCoeff1, var=u2) ...
  ... ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=sourceCoeff2, var=u1) ...
  ```
- As pointed out by @wd15 in the comments, you are declaring four equations for two unknowns. `&` does not mean "add two equations together" (which can be accomplished with `+`), rather it means "solve these two equations simultaneously". So, write

  ```py
  sourceCoeff1 = mu1*u1/(K+u1)
  sourceCoeff2 = mu2*u2/(K+u1)

  eq1 = (TransientTerm(var=u1) 
         == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D1, var=u1) 
         + ConvectionTerm(coeff=convCoeff, var=u1) 
         - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=g, var=u1) 
         - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=sourceCoeff1, var=u2))
  eq2 = (TransientTerm(var=u2) 
         == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D2, var=u2) 
         + ConvectionTerm(coeff=convCoeff, var=u2) 
         - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=g, var=u2) 
         + ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=sourceCoeff2, var=u1))

  eqn = eq1 & eq2
  ```
- A `CellVariable` must be declared with `hasOld=True` in order to call `updateOld()`, so

  ```py
  u1 = CellVariable(name="u1", mesh=mesh, value=u10, hasOld=True)
  u2 = CellVariable(name="u2", mesh=mesh, value=u20, hasOld=True)
  ```

Full code that seems to work is [here](https://gist.github.com/guyer/a8c09f92e0196b5a37df1d69e8a2e0cc)

Comment: How thanks for this complete answer.
I have taken a long time to check because I was dragged to another project and I just came back to this one.
Everything is clear on how to use Fipy in this case. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy to help

Comment: @jeguyer, is there any way to update the variables u1 and u2 at each time step?

Comment: and boundary conditions

Comment: @IgorMarkelov : I'm not sure what you mean. u1 and u2 are solution variables, so they are automatically updated at each time step. If you wish to force some part of u1 or u2 to be different from the solution at each time step, you can do that with `.setValue()`. Time dependent boundary conditions are illustrated in about 1/3 of the way down in [`examples/diffusion/mesh1D.py`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.mesh1D.html). Please open a new question for any further discussion of these questions.